# How to set a HTTP timeout when retrieving RDF from a URI?

Tags: java, timeout, rdf, jena

I am resolving RDF URIs in a Servlet using Jena:

```
final Model rdfModel = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
rdfModel.read(resource);
```

Is there a possibility to set Http Connect and Socket timeouts in Jena?

Or is it the only option to do handle the http connection 'manually' using Apache HttpClient?

```
final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
params.setParameter(HttpConnectionParams.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 1000);
params.setParameter(HttpConnectionParams.SO_TIMEOUT, 5000);
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the design of the API, it appears that you should be able to  use [`HttpOp#setDefaultHttpClient()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-arq/2.11.0/org/apache/jena/riot/web/HttpOp.java#HttpOp.setDefaultHttpClient%28org.apache.http.client.HttpClient%29) to modify the default `HttpClient` utilized within Jena.

[`HttpOp#execHttpGet(String,String)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-arq/2.11.0/org/apache/jena/riot/web/HttpOp.java#HttpOp.execHttpGet%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29) is delegated to by [`LocatorURL#open(String)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-arq/2.11.0/org/apache/jena/riot/stream/LocatorURL.java#LocatorURL.open%28java.lang.String%29), which is called by the `StreamManager` used by `RDFDataMgr`. Elsewhere, [HttpOp#ensureClient(...)](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-arq/2.11.0/org/apache/jena/riot/web/HttpOp.java#HttpOp.ensureClient%28org.apache.http.client.HttpClient%2Corg.apache.jena.atlas.web.auth.HttpAuthenticator%29) substitutes in the default client, if it is present.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the code based on @rob-hall's hint:

```
final Model rdfModel = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
params.setParameter(HttpConnectionParams.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 1000);
params.setParameter(HttpConnectionParams.SO_TIMEOUT, 5000);
HttpOp.setDefaultHttpClient(httpclient);
rdfModel.read(resource);
```

Comment: Yea, I should have just put the solution code at the end of my answer.